# SBUF/SCON 8085 Serial Communication

Tags: microcontroller, programmable-logic

While using 8085 especially at a different baud-rate ,
DTE being the micro-controller, DCE being any modem/or a Display device coupled with 
RS232 db9 or db25 port.
I can understand SBUF can Store upto 8 bit of data when its full, it gives A TI high
ie it hires a transmitter interrupt,
But  Iam confused whether this SBUF (**mentioned in program**) bleongs to the DTE or DCE,

Suppose there is a program,To transmit at baudrate 4800,
     `ORG 00H;
00   MOV SCON #50H;
01H  MOV TMOD #20H;
02H  MOV TH1,-6;
03H  MOV A,#'Y';
04H  CALL PRINT;
05H  MOV A,#'E';
06H  CALL PRINT;
07H  MOV A,#'S';
08H  CALL PRINT;
09H  CLR TI;
0AH  SJMP 03H;`

`PRINT: MOV SBUF,A;
   P1:  JNB TI,P1;
        RET;`

Also during transmission of 'Y' to the receiver of the DCE, REN flag must be enabled,
there is a need for both the sides to understand the tranmission of data(first 8bit has taken place, which this program seriouly misses) and we use TI for that ,
but can we address both ends SBUF in a single program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SBUF register is continuously monitored by the 8 bit SCON registers.
The bit configuration is given as follows:
`SMO  SCON.7  # SM0 and SM1 decides the mode of operation of 
 SM1  SCON.6    the SCON
 SM2  SCON.5
 REN  SCON.4
 TB8  SCON.3
 RB8  SCON.2
 TI   SCON.1
 RI   SCON.0`

Considering the mode 1 case:
As soon as the data is transferred into the 8 bit SBUF register,is it appended with the stop bit and the start bit,the data before sending issues a **Clear to Send Request Through the RS232 standards**,after **ACK** the signal is sent to the **DCE** end and is stored in the SBUF at DCE.

1)During trasmission from the **DTE** the TI flag represent overflooding of the SBUF,also it indicates Transmission complete.
2)At the receiver the **RTS** (Request to Send ) enables the  synchronization  among DCE and DTE hence making it to receive the Data.

***Hence so to say separate SBUF are needed at both the DCE and the DTE each is controlled by the UART standard set by RS232 Ports***

The SBUF **TI and RI** Flags were designed accordingly for transmission of the bit-by-bit data in my program I am loading a whole ASCII value into the SBUF simultaneously which turns the TI flag high almost instantaneously,
Hence it is advice sable to use bit-by-bit transmission, or using a extra delay while working with strings.

Answer (score 1):

The second line of your print subroutine should be

```
P1:  JNB TI, P1
```

so you don't keep stuffing the character into SBUF.  You should only place a new character in SBUF after the UART says it is ready for a new character.

(Disclaimer: I haven't worked with an 8085 UART for a long time.)